# Getting Servlet to throw Error 404 through Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, nginx, proxy

How do I get my Servlet to throw an error 404 that will be redirected by my Nginx proxy?

It works fine for 404s thrown by Nginx. But if the request is proxied through to Tomcat, the error 404 page comes from Tomcat and not Nginx.

Can I somehow return an error 404 that is then picked up by the Nginx redirect? Or do I need to do a configure a parallel 404 error page in the web.xml?

I have the following included in my nginx config:

```
location ~ \.do$ {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

error_page  404 = @page-not-found;
location @page-not-found {
    rewrite  .*  /search?status=page-not-found permanent;
}
```

And a servlet like:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
    String handle = request.getParameter("handle");     
    Page page = pageDao.getPageByHandle(handle);        
    if(page.getId()!=null){
        request.setAttribute("page", page);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/site/page.jsp").forward(request , response); 
    }
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just add `proxy_intercept_errors on` in the nginx config...

As in:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;

error_page  404 = @page-not-found;
location @page-not-found {
    rewrite  .*  /search?status=page-not-found permanent;
}
```